# XNA / C# - Communication between two unrelated classes

Tags: c#, xna

I'm currently creating a game in XNA (Because Monogame and me doesn't get along.), mostly for exercise and all that.

However, so I have a Character class that player and enemies will inherit from, having these members:

```
protected Texture2D sprite_;
protected Point origin_;
protected Rectangle colBox_;
protected Weapon weapon_;
protected controlPair control_;
protected CharState state_;
protected Actions action_;
```

Which basically is some enums and stuff to have a grip on what the character is doing, while still making it able to calling base.Update() in their own so I can save some code that way. The Player class also have a custom Keyboard object to handle the keyboard input from the user.

Now comes the problem though, I obviously need to handle collisions on the environment and enemies, and doesn't really see a nice solution to this. I'm trying to keep the game Update() to look clean by having everything handled by the classes themselves, making it look like this:

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
this.Exit();

foreach (IUpdating i in entityList)
    i.Update(gameTime);
base.Update(gameTime);
```

I want to stay in this style of handling since it makes the code readable and the only real way I can see is to gather all necessary collision data and put it in a container(List?) that I send into all of these, including those who doesn't need it at all.

So the main question is if there's a way to make two different objects to communicate with eachother without having members, or should I just create all the hitboxes before creating character-derived objects and then shove them into a member holding all the hitboxes for the map at the same time? But then I'd guess I have to have the pointers of the hitboxes so they'll update correctly.

Am I onto some kind of solution or is there a much easier way that I don't know of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposed solution:

Have all the objects that need to be checked for collision implement an interface, say ICollidable, which contains HitBox (as property) and HandleCollision(ICollidable other);

HitBox would be self explanatory, HandleCollision method would modify object on collision with *other* accordingly.

Then have all ICollidable objects in a container (probably a List<>).

```
List<ICollidable> iCollidableList = new List<ICollidable>();
//you add and remove objects to/from list as they come and go
```

Then on every step you can run through the list in nested loop and check all objects with each other, whether collision happened and handle collision on each object individually, eg.

```
foreach(ICollidable obj1 in iCollidableList)
{
    foreach(ICollidable obj2 in iCollidableList)
    {
        if(obj1 != obj2 && HitBoxesIntersect(obj1, obj2))
        {
           obj1.HandleCollision(obj2);
           obj2.HandleCollision(obj1);
        }
    }
}
```

Method HitBoxesIntersect(ICollidable, ICollidable) obviously would check for collision by hitboxes.

Comment: Ah, didn't really think of using interfaces for that too, I'm gonna try something along those lines. Thanks for the proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have a game board, and it have a function that allows an object to check each nearby element, and see if it collide with 'em. you can use spatial hashing([tutorial](http://conkerjo.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/spatial-hashing-implementation-for-fast-2d-collisions/)) to havoid testing each item vs the whole list.

```
 Public overrides sub Update(Gametime gametime) 
   foreach (IUpdating i in entityList)
      i.CollideWith(testCollistion(i))
      i.Update(gameTime);
     base.Update(gameTime);
 end sub

 Function TestCollision(myentity as Entity) as Entity
  //test collision as per the tutorial 
  //return nothing if it doesnt collide, or the colliding entity if is does
 end function
```

And in your entity class, you can have the sub collideWith that will handle what happens when you collide with a specific type of entity (enemy, allies, atc )

```
Overridable Sub CollideWith(entity as Entity)
  if not IsNothing(entity) then 
     //set your FSM or any direct actions depending on the results
     If typeof entity is EnemyEntity then ReceiveDamage(entity.attack)
     If typeof entity is NPCEntity then TalkTo(entity) 
  end if
 end sub
```